# Show that $\mathrm{span}(1 + x, 3 - 2x^2)$ is a subspace of $P_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that to show that a subset $S$ is a subspace of $V$:

1. Show $S \neq 0$,
2. If $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \in S$, then $\alpha x \in S$
3. If $x, y \in S$ then $x + y \in S$.

But I don't understand what to do anymore with algebraic expressions in span. Could someone explain the process of solving this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you define the span of a subset of a vector space?

Comment: The set of all linear combinations of a set in the vector space...

Comment: And which of the three properties that you should check whether they hold or not for $\operatorname{span}(1+x,3-2x^2)$ are you unable to check?

Comment: Let $S=$Span$\{u,v\}$.  To prove it is a subspace start with some $w,z \in S$. So $w=c_1u+c_2v$ and $z=d_1u+d_2v$. Then $w+z=(c_1+d_1)u+(c_2+d_2)v$ and so on..

Comment: I think I understand what I have to check, if the span is nonempty, if multiplying one of the vectors by a scalar value returns another vector in P2R, and if adding two vectors returns a vector also in P2R....I just don't understand how I do that with this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a(x), b(x) \in S$, then $a(x)=c_1(1+x)+c_2(3-2x^2)$ and $b(x)=d_1(1+x)+d_2(3-2x^2)$. Then
$$a(x)+b(x)=c_1(1+x)+c_2(3-2x^2)+d_1(1+x)+d_2(3-2x^2).$$
Thus
$$a(x)+b(x)=\underbrace{\color{red}{(c_1+d_1)}}_{\text{scalar}}(1+x)+\underbrace{\color{blue}{(c_2+d_2)}}_{\text{scalar}}(3-2x^2) \in S.$$
Thus it is closed under addition. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, I got it now thanks :) So basically treat the expressions like regular vector values and solve normally. Thanks for taking the time to write out all those steps!

Answer (score 2):

The span of a set of vectors in a vector space is always a subspace.  It's a  subset that is a vector space, by the definition of $\rm{span}$.